# custom .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all to one script e.g. `index.php?url=inputurl`

With if/else I want to parse url

in index.php run query for url in my custom table

- **if** url is mach: echo "ok"
- **else** do nothing

**How should I set .htaccess in root folder of Wordpress?**

Example:

URLs in custom_table:

- asd
- dfg
- ghj

**If** user puts:

www.mysite.com/asd

-> mod_rewrite should output this: www.mysite.com/index.php?url=asd

**Else** if user puts:

www.mysite.com/zzz

-> do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following .htaccess should solve the problem:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirects everything that is not index.php to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,R]
```

**Edit:** to not include your folders and files (like /js, /css, etc.) in rewrite, add the following lines before the `RewriteRule` line (see comments):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And in the PHP script:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];

// the method is_valid should check if the page exists in DB
if (is_valid($url)) {
    // do something here
    // maybe redirect with header('Location: path')
} else {
    // show a not found page (error 404)
}
```

Comment: Chances are he also needs a `RewriteCond` to check if the URL refers to an actual file on the disk, because most likely he doesn't want image/css/javascript files to go through `index.php`. This `RewriteCond` would render the one you've got obsolete.

Comment: @abhi Sure, I've not considered that. Adding these two lines before the RewriteRule should solve this, rigth?
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Answer (score 2):

You want to both be able to read from a database and do nothing if there is not match.

This would require you run code to access db then return back to apache to process and is not possible from .htacccess (though it is from httpd.conf).

The .htaccess solution would be to specify all the "table" entries inline as below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if asd or dfg or ghj
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(asd|dfg|ghj) [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```